# fixed background image and absolute positioned wrapper

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue only on Google Chrome. Basic CSS styles don't behave the same on the two browsers and I can't understand why.

Here is the behavior on Firefox, which is the desired result:

[image]

And here is the behavior on Chrome, which is not good because the image goes down on scroll:

[image]

You can reproduce it on this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zcugdayv/26/

I tried to reduce the code to minimum in order to solve the problem:

```css
.app {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.parallax-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('http://m0.libe.com/blogs/cache/3e/9f/3e9f3c94db337827f6d1d0a859a433f4.jpg') fixed center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.normal-wrapper {
  height: 600px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="parallax-wrapper"></div>
  <div class="normal-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

I know that if I don't use a `position: absolute;` on the `app` class it works again, but I need this for different reasons.

**Do you think it's a bug from Google Chrome itself and that it's gonna be fixed in future releases or if it's something new implemented by Google Chrome itself for a particular reason?**

**If the behavior on Google Chrome is normal, why does the image goes down? What are the maths in what I see?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updated snippet:

Take a look at this code I think this can solve your probelm:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#app {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
}

div div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
}

div.parallax-wrapper {
  background-image: url('http://m0.libe.com/blogs/cache/3e/9f/3e9f3c94db337827f6d1d0a859a433f4.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div class='parallax-wrapper'></div>
    <div class="normal-wrapper">Hello World</div>
    <div class='parallax-wrapper'></div>
    <div class="normal-wrapper">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Also you can see the result here: 
https://jsbin.com/mebecirino/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. Problem with setting the background on body is that I can only set one image. If I have many blocks, it can't work anymore. (example on this jsfiddle here working on Firefox, and bugging on Chrome:https://jsfiddle.net/zcugdayv/41/)

Comment: @Hammerbot Here is a working parallax background on chrome
https://jsbin.com/jojejaxafa/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Thank you again, indeed your example is working. But, as stated in my question, I need the wrapper box to be absolutely positionned: "I know that if I don't use a `position: absolute;` on the app class it works again"

Comment: @Hammerbot Sorry, My bad.
Can you describe why you need `absolute` positioning?
Maybe we can replace that with something else.

Comment: @Hammerbot I updated my answer check it out and let me know if it helped you with your problem.

Comment: Adding the `position: relative;` to the parent works great, thank you very much for all the time you took to answer the question :) Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure as to why this is happening in Chrome but I've made a workaround for you. Add the following to each of the rules and it should be working fine.

```
.parallax-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.normal-wrapper {
    margin-top: 100vh;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
```

}

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. Problem with setting fixed blocks and margins to the other blocks is the complexity when I add blocks. If I have many blocks, it can't work anymore. (example on this jsfiddle here working on Firefox, and bugging on Chrome:https://jsfiddle.net/zcugdayv/41/)